# In Drupal Commerce, how can I decrease stock of product B when buying product A with rules?

Tags: commerce

I'm having some issues writing some rules for my site.

Let's say I have two products. B and C, as well as a combined product called A. Buying product A should decrease the stock of B and C by 1, but the stock of product A should also always be the lowest stock of B or C.

I can't, for the life of me, find out how to do this, and googling has turned up zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module?  You will somehow need to set up the relationships between A + B + C in Drupal, and Entity Reference is one Rules-module compatible way to do this.

Another more flexible but more complicated way would be to use the [Relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module.